# Wordpress ajax handler function doesn't run (javascript results in success)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm in the process of creating a very simple ajax function, but unfortunately it does not enter the ajax handler function. I'm wondering what is wrong with this code?

Function in functions.php:

```
function set_favourite_order() {
 
    update_user_meta( 1, 'favorder', 'enterajax' );
   
    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
   die();
}
 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_favourite_order', 'set_favourite_order' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_set_favourite_order', 'set_favourite_order' );
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: {
                        "action": 'set_favourite_order',
                        "favourite_order" : "test",
                        "pet_id": 8436
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });  
 } );
```

The ajaxurl in the javascript is the link to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and running it results in a success message every time.

The problem is that the ajax handler does not run. Any idea what's wrong? I've been trying to debug this for a day.

Comment: what inside your console?

Comment: It has 'success' (from the success console.log)

Answer (score 0):

Please return JSON object in your ajax callback function and use dataType : JSON

```
function set_favourite_order() {
   update_user_meta( 1, 'favorder', 'enterajax' );

   // Add this line
   echo json_encode(array('result'=>'Success Message'));
   die();
}
```

In you Js file add dataType.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "JSON", // and all your args
},
success:function(data) {
// This outputs the result of the ajax request
console.log(data.result); // Out should be "Success Message"
});
```

Comment: It doesn't result in the success message, gives me an error.
By the way, I believe you have a typo in the json_encode line, I replaced the `=>` with a `,`

Comment: Ohh Sorry, It was my mistake! it will be an array, Now I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that ajaxurl is a variable that stores the admin-ajax.php path and by default wordpress does not provide admin-ajax.php onto the frontend. So you need to initialize it first. There are various way to use, one popurar way is to [localize](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) the js.

Here is an another shortest way

> 

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```